# How do i send any variable to axios in react (get request)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, get, get-request

I have a jsx file and it has an input and a button. In my API service, there is a get request connected to axios. How can I make a get request in axios and print the incoming data for a value entered in the input?

My react codes

```html
export default function HexFind() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <br />
                <br />
                <form>
                    <div className="a">
                        <Image spaced="center" size="medium" src="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="b">
                        <Input fluid placeholder='Hex ID giriniz' name="txtbox"></Input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="c">
                        <Button style={{ background: '#06AE57', color: 'white' }} >Hex Ara</Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br />
                <br />
                <Grid celled>
                        <Grid.Row>
                            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                                Hex ID: 
                            </Grid.Column >
                            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                                Reason:
                            </Grid.Column>
                            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                                Date:
                            </Grid.Column>
                            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                                Server:
                            </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My axios connection service

```html
    import axios from 'axios'

export default class SearchService{
    searchHex(hexId) {
        return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/datas/getByHexId?hexId="+hexId)
    }
    
}
```

And this is my api swagger screen

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfrk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from which library you are importing the elements *Button* y *Input* but you can do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const [hexId, setHexId] = useState(null)

const handleButtonClick = () => {
    axiosCall().then(resp =>{
      console.log(resp)
    })
}

const axiosCall = () => {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/datas/getByHexId?hexId=' + hexId)
}

const Form = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      
      <div className="b">
        <Input fluid placeholder="Hex ID giriniz" name="txtbox" onChange={e =>setHexId(e.target.value)} ></Input>
      </div>
      <div className="c">
        <Button style={{ background: '#06AE57', color: 'white' }} onClick={ e => handleButtonClick(e)} >Hex Ara</Button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Form
```